# omnilight/yii2-scheduling doesn't give any output

Tags: cron, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using the plugin [omnilight/yii2-scheduling](https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-scheduling). When I'm just executing their commands using terminal in ubuntu, I get no output. Commands I'm executing :

```
php /somepath/vendor/yiisoft/yii2 yii schedule/list
php /somepath/vendor/yiisoft/yii2 yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@app/config/schedule.php 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Even I'm using their command for cronjob

```
* * * * * php /path/to/yii yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@path/to/schedule.php 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm not getting any output (Keep in mind that I'm not using any extension command to make it output the result into any file-by this it should give me output plainly then and there - right ?). Please advise where the problem lies.

Comment: Try to remove `1>> /dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the command - it throws away all output.

Comment: But what about the command I executed directly :  ``` php /somepath/vendor/yiisoft/yii2 yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@app/config/schedule.php ```

Comment: You need to look into the section where it describes [how to use in your  application](https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-scheduling#how-to-use-this-extension-in-your-application).

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, I'm not talking about the usage, I'm just executing their cronjob command directly in terminal. Meaning, by placing "* * * * * php /path/to/yii yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php" will execute the command "php /path/to/yii yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php"  internally by cronjob right ? I'm doing cron's job and directly executing that in terminal. It should give me some output right or do what was scheduled in "schedule.php" ? Its doing neither of those things.

Comment: if you are running the command in the terminal and not adding in the crontab remove the last part as suggested by rob, as looking into the source files for the extension there is `ScheduleController` with `run` action that is called in the command and if you  remove the last part it should at-least show you **Running scheduled command:** as it is the first `stdout` statement in the `actionRun` look [here](https://github.com/omnilight/yii2-scheduling/blob/master/src/ScheduleController.php#L48), on the root of project run `php ./yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php`

Comment: or just `./yii schedule/run --scheduleFile=@console/config/schedule.php`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, What you said is right, may be its not running that's why its not showing any output ? By the way,  Nothing is working I've tried the same command in 2 paths : /vendor/yiisoft/yii2 and /vendor/bin. At both of the paths, I'm getting "Unknown command: schedule/run". I've tried schedule/list , but same error. I think there is some fundamental installation problem of the plugin, atleast for me.

Comment: the command i wrote should be run from the `root` of the project, not inside the `vendor`.

Comment: At root, it says "Could not open input file: ./yii " . So I have to go to inside vendor. FYI, I'm using Yii Basic app